# Objective c - Best practice to handle a button touch event for a button of a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uibutton

What is best practice to handle a button touch event for a button of a custom `UITableViewCell`?

my classes:
`MyViewController`, `MyCustomCell`

I can think of three options:

**First option-** Have the button as a property of `MyCustomCell`, and then add a target to it in the `MyViewController` .m file with `MyViewController` as the target.

`MyViewController` .m file

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customCell";

    MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    [cell.theButton addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(theButtonTapped:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    // Configure the cell...    
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)theButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    MyCustomCell *selectedCell = (MyCustomCell *)sender.superview;

    if (selectedCell) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:selectedCell];
        MyModel *selectedModel = [self.model objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 

        // do something with the model...
    }
}
```

**Second option-** If the custom cell was made in IB, Set the nib File's Owner to be `MyViewController`, implement `buttonTapped:` method in `MyViewController` and connect the button's Touch Up Inside event to the `buttonTapped:` method.

**Third option-** if the custom cell wasn't made in IB, add a target to the button in the `MyCustomCell` .m file with `MyCustomCell` as the target.
Define a `MyCustomCellDelegate` add `@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyCustomCellDelegate> delegate` to `MyCustomCell` and call this delegate when button tapped.
Set `MyViewController` as the cell's delegate when creating cells and implement the `MyCustomCellDelegate` protocol.

`MyCustomCell` .h file

```
@class MyCustomCell;  

@protocol MyCustomCellDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)buttonTappedOnCell:(MyCustomCell *)cell;
@end

@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *theButton;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyCustomCellDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

`MyCustomCell` .m file

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.theButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        self.theButton.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,50,30);
        [self addSubview:self.theButton];

        [self.theButton addTarget:self
                           action:@selector(theButtonTapped:)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)theButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.delegate buttonTappedOnCell:self];
}
```

`MyViewController` .m file

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customCell";

    MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        cell.delegate = self;
    }

    // Configure the cell...    
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)buttonTappedOnCell:(MyCustomCell *)selectedCell
{
    if (selectedCell) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:selectedCell];
        MyModel *selectedModel = [self.model objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // do something with the model...
    }
}
```

Comment: I would go with option 1. It seems the most readable for me. I use a similar approach, but I set the delegate in the custom cell and handle the button in the custom cell itself and then call a function in the view controller by checking if the delegate is there.

Answer (score 12):

Store the row of the cell as `tag` property of your custom button.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // bla bla bla
    if (!cell)
    {
        //bla bla bla
        [cell.yourButton addTarget:self selector:@selector(yourButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    // bla bla bla
    cell.yourButton.tag = indexPath.row;
}

-(void)yourButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    int tag = [(UIButton *)sender tag];
    NSLog(@"tapped button in cell at row %i", tag);
}
```

Comment: Is there a benefit doing this and not what i have done? MyCustomCell *selectedCell = (MyCustomCell *)sender.superview;

Comment: Last time I checked, a button in custom cell would have cell's content view as superview.

Comment: The button should be added to the contentView, whose superview is the cell.

Comment: I add it in MyVustomButton class with [self addSubview:button]; is it a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Using tag, from my point of view, would break the strictness of your code. In addition, when you have multiple sections, using tag definitely would make a mess of your code.

To avoid this problem, you can subclass `UITableViewCell` and make it hold an `indexPath` property to let the cell know its precise position.

Another problem here is, if `UITableView` invokes API to `insert` or `delete` row, you have to update visible cells' position data

I don't think that is the best practice.

There exists a better way.

---

**I strongly recommend to use MVVM when you have to handle different touch events in your Cell.**

In this pattern, your custom `UITableViewCell` would hold a custom `CellViewModel`. This class would be responsible for holding all data you associate with the cell, so you can retrieve the data and put the event handling logic inside the cell.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented block based approach by subclassing UIButton :

```
typedef void (^ActionBlock)(id sender);

@interface UIBlockButton : UIButton {
     ActionBlock _actionBlock;
 } 

-(void)handleControlEvent:(UIControlEvents)event withBlock:(ActionBlock) action;
​@end

@implementation UIBlockButton

 -(void) handleControlEvent:(UIControlEvents)event withBlock:(ActionBlock) action
    {
      _actionBlock = action;
      [self addTarget:self action:@selector(callActionBlock:) forControlEvents:event];
      }

  -(void) callActionBlock:(id)sender{
     _actionBlock(sender);
   }

@end
```

And in tableview delegate :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!cell)
    {
     cell.yourButton.tag = indexPath.row;// pass tag
     [cell.yourButton handleControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside withBlock:^(id sender) {
     // your selector action code
     NSLog(@"tapped button in cell at row %i",[(UIButton *)sender tag]);
     }];
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At some point your button is tapped, and at that point it is a subview of a cell which is a subview of some tableview.

Just write a method that takes a view, goes up the superview chain to find the containing cell, goes further up to find the tableview, and then asks the tableview for the indexPath of the cell.

That is a lot easier and more reliable than storing a tag containing a row, because you don't run into problems when tableview is edited, and it's much better to have code that finds out which indexPath it is when you need the indexPath, and not in some completely unrelated code when the cell is created.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0 Solution**

```
cell.btnRequest.tag = indexPath.row

cell.btnRequest.addTarget(self,action:#selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {

    let buttonRow = sender.tag
 }
```