# AVAudioPlayer in cell, how to not release?

Tags: objective-c, memory, avaudioplayer

I've a collection view with custom cell class.

In each cell I've a player with a specific sound.
When made an Button and link to my code with an IBOutlet, it's doesn't fire even with the fact I have `userInteractionEnabled = YES` in all my views.

So I decided to play the sound in the collection view controller.
In my cell the player has a property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *voicePlayer;
```

Then in the collection I have:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    LHFriendVoiceCollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"LHFriendVoiceCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    LHFriendVoiceObject *currentFriendVoice = [[LHFriendVoiceObject alloc] initWithNSDictionnary:[self.friendsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [cell hydrateWithFriendVoiceObject:currentFriendVoice];
    [cell.voicePlayer prepareToPlay];
    //[self.voicesArray addObject:cell.voicePlayer]; tried to stock them in array but doesn't work
    return cell;
}
```

If I play the sound in this method it's work, but I want the sound to be played when I select the cell.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   LHFriendVoiceCollectionViewCell *cell = 
       [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"LHFriendVoiceCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   [cell.voicePlayer play];
}
```

Here the sound doesn't play because voicePlayer is nil.
How I can keep my players ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is the problem:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   LHFriendVoiceCollectionViewCell *cell = 
       [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"LHFriendVoiceCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   [cell.voicePlayer play];
}
```

That first line is wrong. You are calling `dequeue`. Big mistake! It makes a completely new cell. Do not make a new cell like that! Obviously that new cell will not have any AVAudioPlayer in it.

You already have a cell; it just got selected. Use the `indexPath` and `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` to learn out *which* cell got selected. That is the one you want to talk to.

PS You really should figure out why the button approach didn't work, but it's no big deal at this point.

Comment: Thx for the answer, I know it was something like that, but didn't know how to retrieve the cell otherwise, maybe I'm a bit tired. :D
For the button, it's seems normal that it doesn't fire: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796668/objective-c-best-practice-to-handle-a-button-touch-event-for-a-button-of-a-cus